# How to get road name from my location using google map not the location address

Tags: android, google-maps, directions

I want to get the road name in google map when I drive a car on the road using my current location, I searched more about this, but I can not find the solution.
I am using the geocoder to get my location name, but it return the location address not the road that I drive a car on it.
I.e, goecoder return address line as example (5- street , locality, country)
When I drive on the road for 10 meters the address changed to be  (6- street , locality, country)
But I want only the long road name only like (street 5)
I tried to user feature name ot any key in geo coder but it return the address like(5- street 5)
Any one can help me please?

Comment: I don't see the issue.  Yes, the reverse geocoder will return you an address nearest to the LAT/LON position of your current location, but that will include the name of the road you are on.  You can just strip out the parts you don't want.  If I'm not understanding your issue, please clarify it.

Comment: the address like (1600 Ampitheater Parkway), I want only road name (Ampitheater Parkway), how can I get the road name only from address line

Comment: the address like (1600 Ampitheater Parkway), I want only road name (Ampitheater Parkway), how can I get the road name only from address line

Comment: please chack the edit i made on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get your address line from the geocoder, you can make a call to get a string using getThoroughfare, this will get you a street address, such as "1600 Ampitheater Parkway", then, you can make a call to get a string using getSubThoroughfare, which if not null, may return the address part of the Thoroughfare, such as "1600" in the example posted above.  Then, you can do a string replace on the Thoroughfare string replacing Sub-Thoroughfare with "" to strip out the number.

Comment: But I want the road name only as (Ampitheater Parkway)

Comment: The documentation is not very clear and it may not work for every location, but .getAddressLine(0) should return the whole address - '1600 Ampitheater Parkway Cupertino CA 95801', address.getThoroughfare() should return just 'Ampitheater Parkway' (though the documentation showed it with the address), and address.getSubThoroughfare() should return just '1600'.  I would use address.getThoroughfare() and see if that works for you.

Comment: i already tried to use address.getThoroughfare() and address.getSubThoroughfare() and feature name, but no way to get the road name

Comment: Can you show exactly what you get from address.getAddressLine(0) and also exactly what you get from address.getThoroughfare() and also what you get from address.getSubThoroughfare()?  It's possible that the addresses are not well geocoded in the area you are testing from.  You can start with hard-coding a LAT/LON that you pass to the geocoder for someplace famous like the Eiffel Tower in Paris France, 48.886787, 2.295309

Answer (score 1):

you can use this piece of code that i'm using

```
   public String ReverseGeocodingStreet(Double lat,Double lng){
    String street= "";
    if(gc.isPresent()){
        List<Address> list = null;
        try {
            list = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng,1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = list.get(0);
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        street = address.getThoroughfare();
    }
    return  street;
}
```

Comment: No, this code return the address like (1600 Ampitheater Parkway), I want only road name (Ampitheater Parkway)

Comment: No, this code return the address like (1600 Ampitheater Parkway), I want only road name (Ampitheater Parkway)

Comment: i already tried to use address.getThoroughfare() and address.getSubThoroughfare() and feature name, but no way to get the road name

Comment: so you may have a problem with your location (lat,lng) problem